# Get correct records relying on "fake" column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

```
   SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT soi.value, srv.osp_id, soi.stya_id, eoax.estpt_id, eoax.discount, int_sero.id AS sero_id, 2 as attr_number 
     FROM srv_obj_attr_intermediate soi
     JOIN estpt_objt_attr_xref eoax ON eoax.interest_rate = 1
     JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eoax.attr_id
     JOIN object_attribute_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
     JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
     JOIN service_objects int_sero ON int_sero.id = soi.sero_id
     JOIN services srv ON srv.id = int_sero.srv_id
     JOIN order_event_types oet ON oet.code = 'CALC_INTERMEDIATE_ESTP'
     WHERE eoax.ordet_id = oet.id AND eoax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id
        AND soi.stya_id = sta.id AND soi.value = 1

     UNION

    SELECT soa.value, srv.osp_id, soa.stya_id, eoax.estpt_id, eoax.discount, int_sero.id AS sero_id, 1 as attr_number
    FROM srv_obj_attributes soa
    JOIN estpt_objt_attr_xref eoax ON eoax.interest_rate = 1
    JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eoax.attr_id
    JOIN object_attribute_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
    JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
    --LEFT JOIN srv_obj_attr_intermediate soi ON soi.stya_id = sta.id
          --AND soi.value = 1
    JOIN service_objects int_sero ON int_sero.id = soa.sero_id
    JOIN services srv ON srv.id = int_sero.srv_id
    JOIN order_event_types oet ON oet.code = 'CALC_INITIAL_ESTP'
    WHERE eoax.ordet_id = oet.id AND eoax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id
      AND soa.stya_id = sta.id AND soa.value = 1 --AND soi.value IS NULL
  )
) intrate ON intrate.estpt_id = estpt.id 
 AND intrate.sero_id = esero.sero_id 
 AND intrate.osp_id = srv.osp_id --This parameters are served. For this example we replaced srv.osp_id to 619771
```

This select returns me this records

```
|VALUE                                  |OSP_ID       |STYA_ID      |ESTPT_ID                               |DISCOUNT                               |SERO_ID      |ATTR_NUMBER                            |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|-------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------|---------------------------------------|
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
```

I need to add check on each select has own `attr_number`. Based on this column i need to return records.

If records `exists` with `attr_number = 1`, then i should get records only those records.

If records `do not exists` with `attr_number = 1`, then i should get records only where `attr_number = 2`.

I was trying to play around to solve my issue and you can see commended lines(where is `left join` and `soi.value IS NULL`), but it's not working as i described. He is not checking if records exists.

Yes, we should use `union` to remove duplicate rows.

This select is used in `left outer join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `analytical function` as follows:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        Min(attr_number) over(
            partition by value, stya_id, espt_id) as min_a
    from (
        -- your `union` query
    ) t
) t
where attr_number = min_a
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rank()` to filter the resultset:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(
            partition by osp_id, stya_id, espt_id, sero_id 
            order by attr_number desc
        ) rn
    from (
        -- your big `unioon` query
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

I made assumptions about the `partition` since you did not exactly said which columns define a group.

---

You tagged your question Oracle 10g. Note, however, that if you were to use Oracle 12c, this would be simpler done with a row limiting clause:

```
    select t.*
    from (
        -- your big `unioon` query
    ) t
    order by rank() over(
            partition by osp_id, stya_id, espt_id, sero_id 
            order by attr_number desc
        )
    fetch first 1 rows with ties
```

Comment: Let me test it up :). I will let you know how it works.

Comment: @Viktor: no -this is a QA site for *enthousiast programmers*, not a free-lancing service.If something is wrong with the result, please explain what. Also, you should be probably be showing the result that you expect by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60498048/edit).

Comment: Sorry, it's hopelessness. Yeah, you're right that there should be more, as i mentioned i just cut it to show an example. http://prntscr.com/ralv9h As you can see, in this case he is returning me wrong values. Those witch are in red square should be "hidden". So only where `attr_number = 1` should stay.